# Calculate Dv01 of SOFR futures position

Tags: futures, sofr, rates

may I know how to arrive at $3.8m/DV01 SOFR futures based on the net long 3M SOFR as at 13 Dec. The net long is 23,333.

Original Text: Hedge funds were net buyers in around \$3.8m/DV01 SOFR futures over the week, turning net long the futures for the first time since March; further out the curve hedge funds extended net short position in five- and 10-year note futures by combined \$5.9m/DV01”. Source: BBG

[image]

Comment: This question has already one answer on Reddit https://www.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets/comments/zr9g9i/dv01_of_sofr_futures_net_position/